# CalendarView not visible in API 22 and below

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I have this xml where I display a CalendarView and bunch of buttons.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawerActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.teamtreehouse.oslist.MainActivity4">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <CalendarView
                    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/calendarView"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:stretchColumns="0"
                    android:textAlignment="center">

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/trackAttendance"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/mybuttons"
                            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                            android:paddingRight="30dp"
                            android:text="Track Class Attendance"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="17dp"></Button>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/trackSessions"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/mybuttons"
                            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                            android:paddingRight="30dp"
                            android:text="Track Study Sessions"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="17dp"></Button>
                    </TableRow>

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/trackActivities"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/mybuttons"
                            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                            android:paddingRight="30dp"
                            android:text="Track Class Activities"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="17dp"></Button>
                    </TableRow>

                </TableLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:background="#ffeeeeee"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried installing signed APK in devices running on 5.0.2 or less and found out that CalendarView was not displaying at all. In fact just the month and year is displaying.
The CalendarView is visible in API 23, but below that it is not visible. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
This is the stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Canvas_Delegate$11.draw(Canvas_Delegate.java:974)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.drawOnGraphics(GcSnapshot.java:654)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.drawInLayer(GcSnapshot.java:606)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.draw(GcSnapshot.java:582)
at android.graphics.Canvas_Delegate.draw(Canvas_Delegate.java:937)
at android.graphics.Canvas_Delegate.drawText(Canvas_Delegate.java:960)
at android.graphics.Canvas_Delegate.native_drawText(Canvas_Delegate.java:847)
at android.graphics.Canvas_Delegate.native_drawText(Canvas_Delegate.java:859)
at android.graphics.Canvas.native_drawText(Canvas.java)
at android.graphics.Canvas.drawText(Canvas.java:1665)
at android.widget.CalendarViewLegacyDelegate$WeekView.drawWeekNumbersAndDates(CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.java:1434)
at android.widget.CalendarViewLegacyDelegate$WeekView.onDraw(CalendarViewLegacyDelegate.java:1355)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15231)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15140)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3396)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2603)
at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3391)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4110)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15140)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1689)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15140)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1229)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15140)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:601)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:323)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:359)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Maybe you use some methods that are only for API 23, and not applicable on API 22 and below. You can check this [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) for API level 22 to check its content. If the methods and attributes are in color gray, it means that is only for API level 23. You can also see here what method is already deprecated in API level 23.

Comment: @KENdi I have just the basic calendarview with width and height property set.still not visible just for api 22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using deprecated methods like `setSelectedWeekBackgroundColor`, `setUnfocusedMonthDateColor` in my class file. Removed those lines and replaced it with xml code. Now its working fine.

**EDIT**
Still not working

**EDIT2**
finally working used hardcoded height for calendar

Comment: I was using `wrap_content` as the height attribute for the calendar and with your hint to use a fixed height the calendar is visible also below API 22.